# i18next Displayed key instead of value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internationalization, i18next

I have `translation.json` file in `/locales/en/`

```
{
    "app": {
        "name": "Example App"
    }
}
```

In `html`, I have:

```
<a href="/" data-i18n="app.name">
```

In `js`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var language_complete = navigator.language.split("-");
    var language = (language_complete[0]);

    console.log('language', language);

    $.i18n.init({
        lng: language,
        fallbackLng: false,
        debug: false
    }, function() {
        $('a').i18n();
    });
});
```

It displayed `app.name` instead of `Example App`. What i missed in my code? Thanks

Comment: Do you include the jQuery version of i18next? :)

Comment: same problem here, how did you solve it? thanks..

Answer (score 1):

as of i18next V2, the *backend* is no longer provided out of the box ([see the migration guide](https://www.i18next.com/misc/migration-guide#v-1-11-x-to-v-2-0-0)), so you're required to define a `backend` configuration in the init block:

```
backend: {
    loadPath: '/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json'
},
```

if you don't do that, your resources will not be loaded, and translation values will fallback to their respective keys ([see the source code](https://github.com/i18next/i18next/blob/d29425f38383719b8b641274fad5f5c6a614d1c9/src/Translator.js#L108)).

Answer (score 0):

You have to set **useLocalStorage** and **useDataAttrOptions** to true

```
$.i18n.init({useLocalStorage: true , useDataAttrOptions:true, ....});
```

Answer (score 0):

In js it's because `$(document).ready` doesn't wait for external contents to be loaded. You need to use `$(window).on('load',function(){...})`.