# i18next Displayed key instead of value, TVOs, js

Tags: javascript, tvos, i18next

I have similar problem to this one but i did all they wrote and still its something wrong [i18next Displayed key instead of value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18265036/i18next-displayed-key-instead-of-value)

I have translation.json file in /locales/en/

```
  {
    "Ustawienia"    :   "Settings",
    "O aplikacji"   :   "About Application"
   }
```

In application.js

```
function launchApp(options) {
    var javascriptFiles = [
        `${options.BASEURL}js/i18next.min.js`,
        `${options.BASEURL}js/i18next-xhr-backend.min.js`,
        `${options.BASEURL}templates/MainTemplate.js`,
];
evaluateScripts(javascriptFiles, function(success) {
        if(success) {

            i18next.use(i18nextXHRBackend);
            i18next.init({
                lng: userLanguage,
                debug: true,
                fallbackLng: false,
                keySeparator: false,
                nsSeparator: false,
                useLocalStorage: true ,
                useDataAttrOptions:true,

                //resGetPath :  '/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
                backend: {
                    loadPath: options.BASEURL + '/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json'

                },


            }, (err, t) => {
  // initialized and ready to go!


                    });

            var doc = new MainTemplate().getTemplate();
            doc.addEventListener("select", handleMainNavigationClick);
            mainDocument = doc;
            navigationDocument.pushDocument(doc);
            setTimeout(dismissModalView, 2000);
        }
```

and when i want to use i18next.t in template for example

```
<title>${i18next.t("Ustawienia")}</title>
```

It show key(Ustawienia) instead of value (Settings) do you have any tips for me what i'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem might be the place in which you initialise `mainDocument`. The callback from `i18next.init()` is not used, but *that* is where you are sure that it actually *is* initialised. Your code should look something like this

```js
if(success) {

    i18next.use(i18nextXHRBackend);
    i18next.init({
        lng: userLanguage,
        debug: true,
        fallbackLng: false,
        keySeparator: false,
        nsSeparator: false,
        useLocalStorage: true ,
        useDataAttrOptions:true,
        backend: {
            loadPath: options.BASEURL + '/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json'

        },
    }, (err, t) => {
        // initialized and ready to go!
        // this is where initialisation-dependent code should go

        // additionally check if there was an error initialising i18next
        if (err === undefined) {
            var doc = new MainTemplate().getTemplate();
            doc.addEventListener("select", handleMainNavigationClick);
            mainDocument = doc;
            navigationDocument.pushDocument(doc);
            setTimeout(dismissModalView, 2000);
        } else {
            // there was an error, handle it
        }
    });

}
```